# Redirect to stored location after confirmation, devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my ConfirmationsController a user is signed in automatically and then is being redirected to a view, which basically just says, hey, you registered sucessfully

```
    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource)
    registration_success_path
end
```

I need this in-between page for marketing purposes. After this page has been "visitet", I want to redirect again, this time to following path

```
after_sign_in_path_for
```

which is a method in the ApplicationController. But this redirect returns nil.

```
    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource)
    registration_success_path and return
    redirect_to stored_location_for(resource) || super
  end
```

What is wrong and how can I get the user back to his location after this in-between view was shown upon confirmation???

Comment: The line `redirect_to stored_location_for(resource) || super` is most likely unreachable due to `registration_success_path and return`.

Comment: Also if you want to automatically redirect after the user has been on a page for a while you need to use javascript to set a timeout and then redirect by setting `window.location`. You can't send two redirects back as its just a single location header.